# Mongo Aggregation returns _id but "id" is null in return

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Hi I'm using aggregation to pull a list of docs and am using project to return just the _id and name.

The trouble is when Im returning to the browser and I set the _id to id. It returns null.

I'm using Graphql and it seems like id isn't even being called since the type field wont run a console.log

Here's the query:

```
const chatrooms = await Chat.aggregate([
  {
    $geoNear: {
      ...geoFilter,
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          isLocal: true,
          isChatroom: true,
          active: true,
        },
        {
          isLocal: false,
          isChatroom: true,
          active: true,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  { $skip: skip },
  { $limit: limit },
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      name: 1,
    },
  },
]);
```

Here's part of the type def. name will populate, id wont.:

```
 id: {
  type: GraphQLString,
  resolve(parentValue) {
    console.log("parentValue", parentValue);
    try {
      return parentValue._id;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e.message);
    }
  },
},
name: {
  type: GraphQLString,
  resolve(parentValue) {
    try {
      return parentValue.name.replace("city-", "").replace("state-", "");
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e.message);
    }
  },
},
```

Seems like some kind of weird rule of Mongo but im not sure since i do this everywhere else in the code and see no difference
*Yes I also tried returning an ID type

Comment: `_id` is returned by _default_ (in the `$project`). If you don't want `_id` in the projection, you can explicitly exclude it.

Comment: @prasad_ Im bringing back the _id fine. The trouble is I can't use 'id' as a field in the return type. I had to change the name and it worked